# footer display problem

Tags: footer

My footer is wide in my worspress page. But in one page it is not wide. How can i fix this problem. I use Simple Job Board plugin.

This is the page with problem.
http://balikesirkolej.com/jobs/sinif-ogretmeni/

This is the page without problem
http://balikesirkolej.com/is-basvurusu/

Comment: check closing html tag in view source seems like some html tag issue

Comment: You need to add two closing `</div>` before footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- There is the two way to resolved this problem.

1 ) **using css**
- Add below css code in your theme style.css file.

```
    .single.single-jobpost .site-content.container {padding-bottom: 0;padding-left: 0;padding-right: 0;width: 100%;}
```

2 ) Please refer snapshot.
- https://www.screencast.com/t/BbtVLE2Q

Comment: thanks for answer. when i remove the container site-content class it fixes. but which part of the code do i need to edit to fix this container site-content class

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your theme footer.php file for that specific page.. you can simply create a page template for that page . For the new template. use a different footer.php file. In that file make the footer 100% in width but to keep the content centered just add a wrapper inside the footer. That's it